# Extending linux root partition with unallocated space

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have set my PC to dual boot Linux and windows 10.

I have cut some space from my `C:/` partition in windows using some program.

now i want to extent the root Linux partition with that unallocated space, I am using **`GParted`** on a live USB but I am not able to do so,

the right click on root and selecting resize not detecting the free space!

What should I do

[image: Gparted now!]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: @Pilot6 I Guess I am not asking about how to resize ! I am asking about That I can't resize !!!!

Comment: If you read "how to resize", you will understand why you can't resize. Unallocated space should be near the partition you want to resize.

Comment: @Pilot6 I read it and i still don't know how to do that! please advise. currently I have made some changes to make the un allocated space be part of the extended partition but I haven't apply yet, should I proceed?

Comment: This is correct. You can proceed, but be prepared to re-install grub if you move the stating point of the partition you boot from.

Comment: great, I know how to reinstall it, I hope nothing goes wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only resize with empty space that is to the right of the partition. You have to move partitions first until the empty space is in the right position.

Comment: Why to the right? It can be to the left as well ;-)

Comment: Not always, and, for most filesystems, that will actually involve moving first and resizing after. I prefer doing those operations one at a time.

Comment: currently I have made some changes to make the unallocated space be part of the extended partition but I haven't apply yet, should I proceed?

Comment: It seems yes. If you want to increase /dev/sda6 then the empty space should be inside the extended partition.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino, i will try now to do that, i have queued 4 operations to do so, i hope it works!

Comment: @BarafuAlbino is correct. I `move` left and `resize` right.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer...

## First backup your data. Data loss or data corruption is possible.

- move sda3 all the way left

  - be prepared that Windows may not boot, if this is your C: drive
  - use Windows install/repair disk to repair, or use boot-repair
- click the `Apply` icon
- resize the left side of sda4 all the way left
- move sda5 all the way left
- click the `Apply` icon
- move sda6 all the way left
- resize the right side of sda6 all the way right
- click the `Apply` icon